# BRANCH SDK FailTrouble initializing Branch

Tags: android, hyperlink, branch, share, branch.io

I'm using branch io version 4.2.0

Sometime i'm able to generate that share link, but sometime its not work properly. Branch IO SDK behaviours is weird.

> BranchSDK: !SDK-VERSION-STRING!:io.branch.sdk.android:library:4.2.0
>
> I/BranchSDK: Http connect exception: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x7bcb89b888: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by
>   peer
>
> BRANCH SDK FailTrouble initializing Branch.  Branch API Error: poor
>   network connectivity. Please try again later.
>
> I/BranchSDK: Branch Error: User session has not been initialized!

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases this happens when you are using wrong branch keys, please verify this by going to Branch Dashboard -> Account Settings -> Branch Key and compare it with your Manifest file Branch Key. Please refer this for more details:

https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#configure-app

Test your Branch Integration by calling *IntegrationValidator.validate* in your MainActivity's onStart(). Check your ADB Logcat to make sure all the SDK Integration tests pass. Make sure to comment out or remove *IntegrationValidator.validate* in your production build.

```
IntegrationValidator.validate(MainActivity.this)
```

While tapping on the link you can set the App in debug mode and see if the data is getting updated in Branch Liveview. You can refer to this (https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#enable-logging) for more details. Make sure that every test passes, you can see this in the Xcode console.

You can verify the setup with our troubleshooting documentation:
https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#troubleshoot-issues

In case this generic solution does not works, please write to support@branch.io.